# Call child function in parent with i18next react

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I used `React.createRef()` to call child method, like that

```
import Child from 'child';    

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.getAlert();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={this.child} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child class like that

```
    export default class Child extends Component {
      getAlert() {
        alert('getAlert from Child');
      }
    
      render() {
        return <h1>Hello</h1>;
      }
    }
```

It works well. But when I want to use i18next to translate child component, I have to add `withTranslation()` to use HOC.

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
class Child extends Component {
      getAlert() {
        alert('getAlert from Child');
      }
    
      render() {
        const { t } = this.props;
        return <h1>{t('Hello')}</h1>;
     }

    }
export default withTranslation()(Child);
```

Then return error:  Function components cannot be given refs.

Means cannot use ref in `<Child />` tag. Is there any way to call child function after add i18next?

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem since the `withTranslation` HOC is using a function component. By wrapping your `Child` component with a HOC you essentially are placing the ref on the `withTranslation` component (by default).

There are multiple ways to fix this problem, here are the two easiest:

1. **Using `withRef: true` >= v10.6.0**

React-i18n has a built in option to forward the ref to your own component. You can enable this by using the `withRef: true` option in the [HOC definition](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#use-ref-greater-than-v-10-6-0):

```
export default withTranslation({ withRef: true })(Child);
```

2. **Proxy the ref using a named prop**

Instead of using `<Child ref={this.child} />`, choose a different prop to "forward" the ref to the correct component. One problem though, you want the ref to hold the component instance, so you will need to assign the ref manually in the lifecycle methods.

```
import Child from 'child';    

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.getAlert();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child innerRef={this.child} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
class Child extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.innerRef.current = this;
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.innerRef.current = null;
      }

      getAlert() {
        alert('getAlert from Child');
      }
    
      render() {
        const { t } = this.props;
        return <h1>{t('Hello')}</h1>;
     }

    }

export default withTranslation()(Child);
```